# Running a javascript script through python using the subprocess library on a raspberry pi and returning values from it

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have accomplished running a js file with the following python script:

import subprocess
subprocess.check_call('npm run test')

The file test.js reads sensor data and is only written in javascript because the only available library for this sensor is a NodeJS library. Now, I want the test.js to return those values everytime it is executed within my python script. How do I do that?

And it is not possible via this method, are there others? I cannot write this js script in python as the library uses NodeJS.

I want to thank everone that tries to help me in advance and if you need more info, simply contact me!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who might ever find himself in the same situation, I have found a workaround that works for me and might even work for you!

So, this is actually quite simple, but only works for a specific application. Here, I have a sensor which is read by a javascript script, but I want a python script to handle the sensor's output value. What I did was:

import subprocess
import os

deadly_string = subprocess.getoutput('npm run test')
not_so_deadly_string = deadly_string[-6:]

print ("value: ", not_so_deadly_string)

I captured the output of the terminal with "subprocess.getoutput". The output of the terminal looks something like this:

nodejs-qmc5883l@....
.....
Declination angle correction: 1
.
.
.
Azimuth= 300.00

The value "300.00" is what I want, so I cut the last 5 characters of the string and that's it....